# Trouble with GROUP BY CASE

Tags: sql, mysql, group-by, case

The following query gives the error "#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)" because of the (Department_Code, Course_Code) line.  When I replace that with just (Course_Code) it works.  However, that's not what I want

```
SELECT * FROM Classes
GROUP BY CASE 
WHEN (1) THEN
 Department_Code
 ELSE CASE WHEN (2) THEN 
  (Department_Code, Course_Code)
 ELSE Class_ID
 END
END
```

How can I group by Department_Code, Course_Code when condition (2) is satisfied?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `case` expression can only return a single value, so you need two `case` expressions. Also, use a single `case` expression for each instead of nesting two inside each other:

```
SELECT * FROM Classes
GROUP BY
  CASE 
  WHEN (1) THEN
    Department_Code
  WHEN (2) THEN 
    Department_Code
  ELSE
    Class_ID
  END,
  CASE 
  WHEN (2) THEN 
    Course_Code
  ELSE
    1
  END
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem but found a simpler way which was to construct a helper field that can then be referenced in the GROUP BY. 
Or you can do the same conditional trick placing it in the GROUP BY so long as you Concat the fields.

```
SELECT *,

If( 'whatever field to check' = 2 , CONCAT(Department_Code,Course_Code), Course_Code) AS 'group1'

FROM Classes
GROUP BY group1
```