# MYSQL Group By With Case WHEN with multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, case-when

I have this query:

```
SELECT `c`.*, `cont_prod`.`custom_field_set_id` AS `custom_field_set_id`,
 `cont_link_cont`.`id` AS `product_text_id`,
 `cf_321`.`value` AS `concept_number`,
 `cf_322`.`value` AS `annee`,
 `cf_323`.`value` AS `saison`,
 `cf_334`.`value` AS `color_id` 
FROM `container` AS `c` 
INNER JOIN `container_product` AS `cont_prod` 
ON c.id = cont_prod.container_id 
INNER JOIN `container_link` AS `cont_link` 
ON cont_prod.container_id = cont_link.container_id 
INNER JOIN `container` AS `cont_link_cont` 
ON cont_link_cont.id = cont_link.link_id  
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `cf_321` 
ON cont_link_cont.id = cf_321.container_id 
AND cf_321.custom_field_id=321 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `cf_322` 
ON cont_link_cont.id = cf_322.container_id 
AND cf_322.custom_field_id=322 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_string` AS `cf_323` 
ON cont_link_cont.id = cf_323.container_id 
AND cf_323.custom_field_id=323 
LEFT JOIN `custom_field_int` AS `cf_334` 
ON cont_link_cont.id = cf_334.container_id 
AND cf_334.custom_field_id=334 
WHERE `c`.`container_class` 
IN ('product') AND c.deleted = 0 
AND cont_link.reason ='product_main_text' 
AND cont_link_cont.container_class='product_text' 
AND cont_link_cont.hidden = 0 
GROUP BY CASE 
    WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_321.value,cf_322.value,cf_323.value,cf_334.value
END
```

But it is not working.
**Basically I need to group by n fields when some conditions are meet.**
What is wrong in this query:

```
GROUP BY CASE 
  WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_321.value,cf_322.value,cf_323.value,cf_334.value
END
```

**EDIT**
So I am expecting the same result as this group by will do:

```
GROUP BY cf_321.value,cf_322.value,cf_323.value,cf_334.value
```

**EDIT2 Solution:**

```
GROUP BY 
CASE WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_321.value END,
CASE WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_322.value END,
CASE WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_323.value END,
CASE WHEN custom_field_set_id=33 THEN cf_334.value END
```

This because as written here [Trouble with GROUP BY CASE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490877/trouble-with-group-by-case?rq=1) CASE WHEN can return only 1 value statement.

Comment: To those who votes -1 without a reason: I am not a mysql expert. I need some help.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot have a `CASE` in a `GROUP BY`.

If, for whatever reason (*?), you need some of your records to be grouped and others to be ungrouped,  then use a `UNION`.

```
select stuff from container join other_stuff
where 
custom_field_set_id != 33
-- NO GROUP BY

UNION  -- or UNION ALL

select stuff from container join other_stuff
where 
custom_field_set_id = 33
GROUP BY pertinent_fields
```

.

(*?) You are not using a function which would make use of a `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I solved following this advice: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490877/trouble-with-group-by-case?rq=1

Comment: Basically my problem is that I needed to group records differently depending on the custom_field_set_id value

Comment: `You cannot have a CASE in a GROUP BY` This isn't true. You absolutely can have a CASE statement in a GROUP By.